# Matplotlib drawing shows too small, change dimensions or size of matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Under win10, Python draws with matplotlib, and the button and font of the figure window are not scaled up with the system.

[image]

Comment: These are not the default dimensions of a plot so you have somehow decided to use something that looks poor, either in your code or your rcParams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the figure size:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

Changing default figure size:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rc('figure', figsize=(10, 5))
```

You can set the `legend` text size using:

```
plt.legend(fontsize=20) # using a size in points
plt.legend(fontsize="x-large") # using a named size
```

For the button:

```
myButton.label.set_fontsize(12)
```

Comment: However, the default button size of the ribbon is still very small, and the default size of the legend and the axis scale is very small.

Comment: @fxw everything is configurable if you just read through the documentation. Everything is just a google search away. Just use *how to change legend size in matplotlib* and so on. I have updated my answer to include legend font configuration. For button size `myButton.label.set_fontsize(12)`

Comment: Thank you very much，Just feel why changing the default value of the system has become so unhuman

Comment: @fxw It's a preference. Please select & upvote the answer if it helped. Thanks.